# MongoDB $setUnion on object ($setUnion but with additional information)

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

stackoverflow community,
I do not often work with big Arrays of Objects within in mongodb
so I have no idea how to solve this problem:

1.
i am working within one file, so obviously it's an `aggregate` witch firstly does an `{$match:{"_id" : ObjectId("5c3f5cb04147b3082648278b")  }},`

2.
ok now I have another step that $project + $filter to filter out some objects, but it is not important for this (i think)

3. I have an array of objects, similar to this

   { 
   "_id": ObjectId(".."),
   "data": 
    [

   ```
   {
     id : 01,
     groupId: 22,
     noteId: 876543
   },
   {
     id : 02,
     groupId: 33,
     noteId: 767676
   },
   {
     id : 03,
     groupId: 22,
     noteId: 876543
   },
   {
     id : 04,
     groupId: 76,
     noteId: 876543
   }
   ```

   ]
   }

but with thousands of entries and more values per object.

Every groupId can have any noteId, but the same groups have always the same noteId.
The Problem: noteIds can be shared between groups.

I added this

```
{ $project: {
                "groupIds": {"$setUnion": "$data.groupId"}
            }}
```

witch gives me all the groupIds
but it is very important that I also get all the related noteId's because 
it is an arbitrary ID in relation with nothing else.

is it possible to somehow union an object by a specified field?
or is there another way to solve this? If I maybe filter for Objects with $in($data.groupId, $setUnion('union from above') I still would not know how to only extract the 2 fields that I need.

thanks for your help in advance

H.M.

Comment: So do you want to get all the unique `groupId` and their corresponding `noteId`?

Comment: yea, basically, but currently i only get all the groupIds with my union and I cannot say witch noteId correspond, because there are fewer noteIds than groupIds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use below aggregation

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$unwind": "$data" },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": {
      "_id": "$_id",
      "groupId": "$data.groupId"
    },
    "noteIds": {
      "$push": {
        "noteId": "$data.noteId",
      }
    }
  }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$_id._id",
    "data": {
      "$push": {
        "groupId": "$_id.groupId",
        "noteIds": "$noteIds"
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

Comment: currently checking this, didn't get it to work (yet) but I am sure your aggregation is right, maybe I explained my problem wrong... still working on it tho...

Comment: You can check the response here https://mongoplayground.net/p/JUJv24BGhZS

Comment: is there a way to remove the overhead of the noteIds within this aggregation? or do I have to do that in code?

Comment: Hi please ask a new question with the proper document and the expected output

Comment: oh sorry, I thought you know what I meant. If you look at this https://mongoplayground.net/p/JUJv24BGhZS  the result for "groupId": 22, contains all the "noteId": 876543, but they always are the same (as I described it in my question "same groups have always the same noteId")
that is why i though this somehow will work with setUnion, but for multiple fields

Comment: sorry, this would be basically the same question again, that is why I do not want to start a new question about this.

Comment: this solution works, but it is a lot of overhead data to handle

Comment: i just asked if its possible to remove the overhead

Comment: What you are talking about?

Comment: if you check at https://mongoplayground.net/p/JUJv24BGhZS {"noteId": 876543} is 2 times in the "noteIds", im my code i have now 100x the same value in the objects. my question (like above) is: is it possible to add same values only once? with Overhead i mean "unnecessary data"

Comment: but there is no need, its just a question if its possible, sorry if i annoy you

Comment: Use `$addToSet` with `noteIds`. Something like this https://mongoplayground.net/p/i7TQoPN_5bd

Comment: thank you! I hope i will someday understand mongodb as good as you, it is an awesome db an querry langauge